# I'm using jenkins with 3 slaves, however I'd like to run jenkins pipeline only on 2 of them

Tags: jenkins

I tried:

```
pipeline  
  agent {lablel slave1 && slave2}
  agent {lablel 'slave1' && label 'slave2'}
```

But it won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can create labels that apply to multiple nodes.  Then, you can specify a single label in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a label 'myGoodNodes' in the Nodes configuration.
Then refer to it as:

```
agent { label 'myGoodNodes' }
```

Comment: Is it possible to run it separately without a configuration on 2 of 3 slaves?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not exactly right. The quotation marks should be around the whole condition. Also, you want to "Or" the two labels instead of "and".

This should do what you want:

```
agent { label 'slave1 || slave2' }
```